# C# mutex equivalent of ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a cross process mutex, and make sure only one instance is running.

I put those code in Main method and start two process, but the second process didn't exit immediately:

```
string name = "Global\\qweqwe";

try {
    new Mutex(true, name);
} catch (Exception) {
    Console.WriteLine("Mutex already exists");
    return;
}
```

Then I switched to pinvoke and it worked:

```
string name = "Global\\qweqwe";

IntPtr mutex = CreateMutex(IntPtr.Zero, true, name);
if (mutex == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    return;
}

if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("mutex already exists");
    return;
}
```

What's wrong with the C# code?

Note: I didn't release the mutex as this is a minimal case.

Comment: So what actually happens

Comment: Removed cpp tag

Comment: Why are you using a Mutex, when you can let the compiler do the work?
Use a lock block and lock against some object in your class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this code to check that `Mutex` already exists and close the process

```cs
var mutex = new Mutex(false, name, out bool createdNew);
if (!createdNew)
{
    //already created
}
```

Another option is to use [`WaitOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=netframework-4.8) method and pass some timeout, like in this snippet

```cs
var mutex = new Mutex(false, name);
if (mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero))
{
    //doesn't created                   
}
else
{
    //already exists, one instance is created                   
}
```

There is also a nice [article](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) about single instance app. It's old and related to WinForms, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

What i personally use in c# is an eventwaithandle in app.cs

```
public static EventWaitHandle ApplicationMutex { get; set; }



        /// <summary>Handles the application startup sequence</summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The App.xaml file</param>
        /// <param name="e"><see cref="StartupEventArgs"></see></param>
        private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) {
            var appName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule?.FileName);

            // We create a mutex here that lasts for the lifetime of our program to stop users from
            // opening two windows at once
            ApplicationMutex = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, appName, out var created);

            if (!created) {

                if (ApplicationMutex != null)
                    Log.Error("Failed to create mutex");

                Current.Shutdown();
            }
```

with the following code in the main window:

```
 ~MainWindow() {
            App.ApplicationMutex.Dispose();
        }
```

this does exactly what you want it to do